# Is it certain that two (new Date()).getTime in one JavaScript file will get two different results?

Tags: javascript

I want to generate unique ids for some variables. I need to create a new id everytime for some variable.

Is it safe to use such kind of code?

```
var id = 'id_' + (new Date()).getTime();
```

I need to make sure there's no duplicate id during running my script.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid) is better suited for your needs

Comment: your ID will only be unqique if two instances of your script are not running at the same millisecond, low chances but not impossible

Comment: try it yourself `(new Date()).getTime() === (new Date()).getTime()` ... oops, it's true

Comment: Why do you need these IDs? There are most likely better ways, e.g. if you want to distinguish multiple objects, use a [`Map`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: `(new Date()).getTime()` the same as `Date.now()`. you can create a function that return new "id" `const getUniqId = () => Date.now()`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's ideal for generating unique ids, I'd suggest using [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) instead. They are *globally* unique, you will never get collisions.

If you make several calls of 'id_' + (new Date()).getTime() in the same millisecond, you will get duplicated ids.

You can easily create UUIDs using the [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) library:

```js
   
const ids = Array.from({ length: 5}, () => uuid.v4());
console.log("Ids:", ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uuid/8.3.2/uuid.min.js" integrity="sha512-UNM1njAgOFUa74Z0bADwAq8gbTcqZC8Ej4xPSzpnh0l6KMevwvkBvbldF9uR++qKeJ+MOZHRjV1HZjoRvjDfNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

You'll see that if you generate a bunch of ids at the same time they can easily be duplicates, so that approach will be very risky:

```js
let ids = Array.from({ length: 5}, () => 'id_' + (new Date()).getTime());

console.log("IDS:", ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

UUID package is recommended of course but perhaps you can still get pretty unique IDs by doing

```
(Date.now()*Math.random()).toString(36).replace(".","").toUpperCase()
```

Lets test a 1000000 successively generated IDs for uniqueness.

```js
var uid      = _ => (Date.now()*Math.random()).toString(36).replace(".","").toUpperCase(),
    uids     = Array.from({length:1000000}, _ => uid())
                    .sort(),
    isUnique = uids.slice(1)
                   .every((id,ix) => id !== uids[ix]);

console.log(isUnique);
```